# One gradient over multiple objects

Tags: svg

I was wondering how I can apply **one** gradient to multiple objects.

Let's say I have ten circles next to each other and a gradient from yellow to red.
All dots together should now show the gradient.

Example:

```css
svg {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 297 345">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="Orange_Gelb" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffff25" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f71818" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
      <g >
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="100" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="200" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="300" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="400" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="500" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: there is no canvas in your code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this is what you were asking for:

```js
// initiate the canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 297);
let ch = (canvas.height = 550);

// create the liniar gradient
// SVG equivalent <linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
let grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
// SVG equivalent: <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffff25" />
grd.addColorStop(0, "#ffff25");
// SVG equivalent: <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f71818" />
grd.addColorStop(1, "#f71818");
ctx.fillStyle = grd;

//draw the circles
for (let y = 100; y < 550; y += 100) {
  drawCircle(90,y,50);
}

function drawCircle(x,y,r) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
svg,canvas{border:1px solid; width:297px;}
```

```html
<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 297 550">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="Orange_Gelb" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffff25" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f71818" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
      <g >
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="100" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="200" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="300" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="400" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="500" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
      </g>
    </svg>

<canvas></canvas>
```

#### UPDATE

I'm adding an other example where the gradient is applied to every circle in part

```js
// initiate the canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 297);
let ch = (canvas.height = 550);


//draw the circles
for (let y = 100; y < 550; y += 100) {
  ctx.fillStyle = Grd(90,y,50)
  drawCircle(90,y,50);
}

function drawCircle(x,y,r) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}


function Grd(cx,cy,r) {
  grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(cx-r,cy-r,cx+r,cy+r);
  grd.addColorStop(0, "#ffff25");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "#f71818");

  return grd;
}
```

```css
svg,canvas{border:1px solid; width:297px;}
```

```html
<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 297 550">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="Orange_Gelb" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ffff25" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#f71818" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
      <g >
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="100" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="200" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="300" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="400" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
        <circle class="c1" cx="90" cy="500" r="50" fill="url(#Orange_Gelb)"/>
      </g>
    </svg>

<canvas></canvas>
```

Please note that in this case the SVG linear gradient uses  `gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"`. In canvas I had to write a function that creates a different gradient for every circle.

Comment: Nice! Thank a lot! I could not find that solution online.
Could you please help me understand how the gradient is applied? It seems like you apply the gradient to the canvas and then draw circles on top? This seems counterintuitive for me. Why is the gradient applied to the canvas and not to each circle?

Comment: You are doing the same in SVG. The gradient is as big as your SVG canvas since you are using `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`. If you change `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` with `gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"`the gradient will be applied to every circle in part.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some comments and an other example where in SVG and canvas I'm applying the gradient to every circle in part.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's really helpful :)